# Error logging in to Google Cloud Registry from Gitlab CI: Cannot perform interactive login from a non TTY device

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci, gcloud

Life is great as I have 2 Gitlab CI projects that should both push docker images to the same directory and both have the some configuration but one is working, one is not...

Working:

```
push_gcp:
  only:
    - master
  image: docker:dind
  before_script:
    - docker login registry.gitlab.com -u ${CI_REGISTRY_USER} -p ${CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD}
    - echo $GCLOUD_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_BASE64 > gcloud-service-key.txt
    - cat gcloud-service-key.txt | docker login -u _json_key_base64 --password-stdin https://europe-west4-docker.pkg.dev
  script:
    - ...
  after_script:
    - docker logout ${CI_REGISTRY}
    - docker logout https://europe-west4-docker.pkg.dev
  stage: push
  allow_failure: false
  tags: 
    - docker
```

[image]

Failing:

```
push_gcp:
  only:
    - master
  image: docker:dind
  before_script:
    - docker login registry.gitlab.com -u ${CI_REGISTRY_USER} -p ${CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD}
    - echo $GCLOUD_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_BASE64 > gcloud-service-key.txt
    - cat gcloud-service-key.txt | docker login -u _json_key_base64 --password-stdin https://europe-west4-docker.pkg.dev
  script:
    - ...
  after_script:
    - docker logout ${CI_REGISTRY}
    - docker logout https://europe-west4-docker.pkg.dev
  stage: push_image
  allow_failure: false
  tags: 
    - docker
```

[image]

Any ideas? I'm going mental here..

Comment: Did you set up the variables per environment variable (one on each project in Gitlab)?
`${CI_REGISTRY_USER}` `${CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD}`

Comment: Please don't include images on Stack overflow. Please copy-and-paste content directly. Image makes it difficult to parse the GitLab output and difficult to review.

Comment: There's no need to `echo ${VAR} > file; cat file | docker login ...`. You can combine this into a single step `echo ${VAR} | docker login ...`. Is it possible that you're not correctly setting `GCLOUD_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_BASE64` in the 2nd example?

Comment: @CaioT Thanks for your reply, the issue is not with the Gitlab docker login. That one is working fine.

Comment: @DazWilkin I tried removing the step, no result.. How can I print / debug if the variable is set correctly? In the variables section everything looks fine.
`$ echo ${GCLOUD_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_BASE64} | docker login https://europe-west4-docker.pkg.dev -u _json_key_base64 --password-stdin
Error: Cannot perform an interactive login from a non TTY device`

Comment: The step removal was an optimistation suggestion not a fix. You should be able to add a line of the form `if [ -z ${GCLOUD_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_BASE64} ]; then echo "Service Account variable is set"; fi` to see a message if the variable is set without publishing it. Please swap the images for pasted text. You can begin and end the pasted block with 3 backticks (```) so that it displays correctly.

Comment: Thank you, I tried this and as to be expected the variable is set correctly. Any other ideas? And I will swap the images soon!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit late but the solution was to disable protected variables in Gitlab CI/CD settings.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 - echo $GCP_SA_KEY > ${HOME}/gcloud-service-key.json
 - docker login -u _json_key --password-stdin https://gcr.io < ${HOME}/gcloud-service-key.json
```

basically after `--password-stdin`, use `<` .

Comment: I tried this, same error..

Comment: @DominicJordan Can you send me what you have tried ?

Comment: Yes, sorry!

`$ docker login https://europe-west4-docker.pkg.dev -u _json_key_base64 --password-stdin < gcloud-service-key.txt
Error: Cannot perform an interactive login from a non TTY device`